# Can't figure out how to get rows based on column values that aren't identical

Tags: sql, sql-like

My problem is this:

Say I hypothetically have a table called fastfood which has one field called fastfood_chains that have values of "Awesome Wendys" and "Peanut Chuck"

Then I have another table called fastfood_info that has a field "fastfood_chain" but the values aren't identical to the other table, it's shortened to "Wendys" or "Chucks"

How would I display all the rows from fastfood_chain and have the results print the full name using the other table instead of just "Wendys" or "Chucks" ?

I assumed it had something to do with the LIKE statement but I'm having difficulties. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If all you have to match the two tables on is these inconsistent names, then good luck.

Comment: I agree with Joe - there's currently no real reliable way to tie 'Peanut Chuck' to 'Chucks' (that dratted 's' on the end - and that's assuming they actually refer to the same place...).  This is why you store foreign keys to a `fastfood_chain` table.  Oh, the wording of this implies (to me) that `fastfood_chains` is some sort of multi-value column (like, say, a comma-separated list) - if so, you're just toast: manual intervention necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to add the "s" at the end. I meant an actual subset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You know that fastfood_chain in second table contains only subsets of fastfood_chain from first table. I didn't quite understand what exact columns do You want in the result, but You can list them with fff and ffc prefix:

```
SELECT * FROM fastfood_chains ffc
INNER JOIN fastfood_info ffi ON 
     ffc.fastfood_chain LIKE CONCAT('%', ffi.fastfood_chain, '%')
```

Please note that this might be extremely slow depending on many factors.

P.S.: I don't have access to MySQL instance at the moment. Hope it works now.
For MSSQL users, the last line should be:

```
     ffc.fastfood_chain LIKE '%' + ffi.fastfood_chain + '%'
```

Comment: i tried this and im getting " You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+ ffi.fastfood_chain + '%' LIMIT 0, 30' at line 4

Comment: This is MSSQL syntax, I'll edit my post right away to MySQL syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Possible way of doing this is:

```
SELECT F.FASTFOOD_CHAIN, I.* 
FROM FASTFOOD F
LEFT OUTER JOIN FASTFOOD_INFO I
ON F.FASTFOOD_CHAIN LIKE '%' || I.FASTFOOD_CHAIN || '%'
```

Comment: i just tried that and I'm getting #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'I'